# How to prevent df.pivot from inserting 'None' and blank rows during pivot?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot

I am wanting to pivot a df that looks like this:

```
columns        values
col1            test1
col2            test2
col3            test3
col4            test4
col1            test5
col2            test6
col3            test7
col4            test8
```

I am trying this:

df['index'] = df.index
df = df.pivot(index='index', columns='columns', values='values')

which results in a df that looks like this (roughly):

```
col1         col2       col3      col4
None         None       test1     None
test5        None       None      None
```

How do I pivot the df to look like this?:

```
col1         col2       col3      col4
test1        test2      test3     test4
test5        test6      test7     test8
```

I am creating an articfical index column because I dont have another column to make an index. I only have 2 columns in the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `cumcount` create a new key then do `pivot`

```
df.assign(key=df.groupby('columns').cumcount()).pivot('key','columns','values')
Out[54]: 
columns   col1   col2   col3   col4
key                                
0        test1  test2  test3  test4
1        test5  test6  test7  test8
```